# Is there a free-boundary elliptic estimate in $L^p$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

Let $\mathbb{D}^2$ be the **closed** two-dimensional unit disk. Let $V \in \Omega^1(\mathbb{D}^2)$ be a smooth one-form.

Does there exist a constant $C$, such that

$$ \vert\vert V\vert \vert_{W^{2,p}(\Omega)} \leq C(\vert\vert \Delta V \vert\vert_{L^p(\Omega)} + \vert\vert V\vert\vert_{L^p(\Omega)}),$$

holds for all one-forms $V$, where $C$ does not depend on the boundary values of $V$?

Here $\Delta=\delta d+d\delta$ is the usual Hodge Laplacian on differential forms*.

The point is that I don't assume any specific boundary conditions on $V$. (So, what is written [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56829/proof-of-lp-elliptic-regularity) for instance does not seem to apply).

**Comment:**

*I am actually interested in a more general case where $\mathbb{D}^2$ is endowed with some smooth Riemannian metric $g$, and the Euclidean Laplacian $\Delta$ is replaced by the Riemannian one w.r.t $g$ (the adjoint $\delta$ depends  on $g$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such $C.$ Define $V_n(x,y)=\mathrm{Re}[f_n(x+iy)]\;dx + \mathrm{Im}[f_n(x+iy)]\;dy$ where $f_n(z)=z^n.$ Then

$$\nabla V=0$$
and

\begin{align*}
\|V_n\|_{L^p(\Omega)}
&=\left(\int_\Omega |f_n(x+iy)|^p\right)^{1/p}\\
&=\left(\int_\Omega r^{np}\right)^{1/p}\\
&=\left(2\pi \int_0^1 r^{1+np}dr\right)^{1/p}\\
&=\left(\frac{2\pi}{2+np}\right)^{1/p}\\
&\sim c_p n^{-1/p}\text{ for some constant $c_p$}
\end{align*}

But

\begin{align*}
\|V_n\|_{W^{2,p}(\Omega)}
&\geq c'\left(\int_\Omega \left|\frac{\partial^2 f_n}{\partial x^2}(x+iy)\right|^p\right)^{1/p}\\
&= c'_pn(n-1)\left(\int_\Omega r^{np-2}\right)^{1/p}\\
&\sim c'_pc_p n^{2-1/p}
\end{align*}
with some other constant $c'_p$ depending on how the Sobolev norm is defined. So $$\|V_n\|_{W^{2,p}(\Omega)}\gg \|\nabla V_n\|_{L^p(\Omega)} +\|V_n\|_{L^p(\Omega)}.$$